# how to join two table column name and yield one result in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

need to clear one doubt on linq

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetAttributeName() 
{ 
   var attri = (from z in _entities.Attributes 
                select z).AsEnumerable()
               .Select(z => new SelectListItem { 
       Text = z.AttributeName + " (" + z.AttributeType.AttributeTypeCode + ")", 
       Value = z.AttributeID.ToString() 
               }); 

  return attri.ToList(); 
}
```

on this line

```
Text = z.AttributeName + " (" + z.AttributeType.AttributeTypeCode + ")",
```

the output will be..
like this..

```
abcd (efgh)
ijkl(mnop)
qrst(uvwx)
```

but i need the output is

```
abcd
ijkl
qrst
efgh
mnop
uvwx
```

How to achieve that..?

Comment: So, you want single attribute displayed in two different lines in combobox?

Comment: i need to display attributename first and then display AttributeTypeCode in a single combobox.. @lazyberezovsky

Comment: That is not what you are doing in your sample output

Comment: concept is this.. i had 2 tables .. that 2 tables contains two column named attributename and AttributeTypeCode respectively. I need to join this two column values and listed in combobox

Comment: Create 2 collections and concat those

Comment: but in linq it is not possible a ah @MichaëlHompus

Comment: EHm, yes it is: [Enumerable.Concat<TSource> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetAttributeName() 
{ 
   return _entities.Attributes
                   .Select(a => new SelectListItem {
                         Text = a.AttributeName,
                         Value = a.AttributeID.ToString() })
                   .Concat(_entities.Attributes.AsEnumerable()
                                   .Select(a => new SelectListItem {
                         Text = a.AttributeType.AttributeTypeCode.ToString(),
                         Value = a.AttributeID.ToString() })
                   .ToList();
}
```

Or in single query to database (previous sample will query database two times):

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetAttributeName() 
{ 
   var attributes = _entities.Attributes
                             .Select(a => new { 
                                  a.AttributeName,
                                  a.AttributeType.AttributeTypeCode,
                                  a.AttributeID
                             }).ToList();

   return attributes.Select(a => new SelectListItem {
                         Text = a.AttributeName,
                         Value = a.AttributeID.ToString() })
                    .Concat(attributes.Select(a => new SelectListItem {
                         Text = a.AttributeTypeCode.ToString(),
                         Value = a.AttributeID.ToString() })
                    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Let me check and tell @lazyberezovsky

Answer (score 0):

I just used this query and got the values perfectly..

```
var attributes = _entities.Attributes.ToList().Select(a => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = a.AttributeName,
                        Value = a.AttributeID.ToString()
                    }).Concat(_entities.AttributeTypes.ToList().Select(a => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = a.AttributeTypeCode,
                        Value = a.AttributeTypeID.ToString()
                    }).Distinct().ToList());

                    return attributes.ToList();
```